# Speech or no speech detection in Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am writing a program that recognizes speech. What it does is it records audio from the microphone and converts it to text using Sphinx. My problem is I want to start recording audio only when something is spoken by the user.

I experimented by reading the audio levels from the microphone and recording only when the level is above a particular value. But it ain't that effective. The program starts recording whenever it detects anything loud. This is the code I used

```
import audioop
import pyaudio as pa
import wav

class speech():
    def __init__(self):
        # soundtrack properties
        self.format = pa.paInt16
        self.rate = 16000
        self.channel = 1
        self.chunk = 1024
        self.threshold = 150
        self.file = 'audio.wav'

        # intialise microphone stream
        self.audio = pa.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.audio.open(format=self.format,
                                  channels=self.channel,
                                  rate=self.rate,
                                  input=True,
                                  frames_per_buffer=self.chunk)


    def record(self)
        while True:
            data = self.stream.read(self.chunk)
            rms = audioop.rms(data,2) #get input volume
            if rms>self.threshold: #if input volume greater than threshold
                break

        # array to store frames
        frames = []
        # record upto silence only
        while rms>threshold:
            data = self.stream.read(self.chunk)
            rms = audioop.rms(data,2)
            frames.append(data)

        print 'finished recording.... writing file....'
        write_frames = wav.open(self.file, 'wb')
        write_frames.setnchannels(self.channel)
        write_frames.setsampwidth(self.audio.get_sample_size(self.format))
        write_frames.setframerate(self.rate)
        write_frames.writeframes(''.join(frames))
        write_frames.close()
```

Is there a way I can differentiate between human voice and other noise in Python ? Hope somebody can find me a solution.

Comment: I am testing your code in ubuntu,
from where wav package to download & test ?

Answer (score 6):

I think that your issue is that at the moment you are trying to record without recognition of the speech so it is not discriminating - recognisable speech is anything that gives meaningful results after recognition - so catch 22.  You could simplify matters by looking for an opening keyword.  You can also filter on [voice frequency range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_frequency) as the human ear and the telephone companies both do and you can look at the mark space ratio - I believe that there were some publications a while back on that but look out - it varies from language to language.  A quick Google can be very informative.  You may also find [this](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1010&context=cis_papers) article interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is just the recording part. I have the recognition part as a separate module. It would be good if you elaborated the frequency range filtration thing. I haven't heard of it. Could you suggest me some documentation or something so that I can learn about that ?

Comment: Added some more details to the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

I think waht you are looking for is [VAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) (voice activity detection). VAD can be used for preprocessing speech for ASR. Here is some open-source project for implements of VAD [link](https://www.google.com.hk/search?newwindow=1&safe=active&client=opera&hs=nru&channel=suggest&biw=1440&bih=762&q=github+voice+activity+detection&oq=github+voice+activity+de&gs_l=serp.3.0.33i21.2398.8137.0.10998.18.18.0.0.0.0.524.2827.0j6j3j2j0j1.12.0....0...1c.1.23.serp..8.10.2404.ESIsA1l51UU). May it help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example script using a VAD library.
https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/blob/master/example.py